# JavaScript: Add or Push values in Object with new Index

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was working with JS Objects. I want to push some values with defined index (id), so that i can access those values after adding/pushing them in the JS Object.

Let suppose this is an object that I created in JavaScript

```
var my_books = {
    1 : {
        'name' : 'Book_1',
        'price' : '100'
    },
    2 : {
        'name' : 'Book_2',
        'price' : '200'
    }
};
```

Now, I want to add below data in the above created object

```
3 : {
    'name' : 'Book_3',
    'price' : '300'
}
```

After adding I want to access it using the below line.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(my_books[3]['name']));
```

But I don't know how to add such data in the Objects of JavaScript. I searched a lot but no code help me in this regard.

Kindly Help.

Comment: Use an array instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
my_books[3] = {
    'name' : 'Book_3',
    'price' : '300'
}
```

But if you want the index to be auto-generated then `objects` are wrong data structure for your requirements. You could consider using `Arrays` instead.

Example:

```
my_books = [];

function newBook (name, price) {
  const newBookObject = {name, price};
  my_books.push(newBookObject);
}

newBook('book1', 100);
newBook('book2', 500);
newBook('book3', 600);

console.log(my_books);

// To iterate over it -
for (var index in my_books) {
  console.log(index, my_books[index]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me how can i create arrays with such indexing scheme ? because i want to add multiple friends data within an array and want to access each friend detail with their id. Please Help

Comment: I do not understand how the actual names (keys, like name and price) are added here but this works very well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can create a custom function push. It can accept the new object to add.

Find the last index inserted and increment the key.

```
function push(obj){
  max  = Object.keys(my_books).reduce((acc, val) => acc > Number(val) ? acc: Number(val) , 0);
  my_books[max + 1] = obj;
  return my_books;
}
```

```js
var my_books = {
    1 : {
        'name' : 'Book_1',
        'price' : '100'
    },
    2 : {
        'name' : 'Book_2',
        'price' : '200'
    }
};



function push(obj){
  max  = Object.keys(my_books).reduce((acc, val) => acc > Number(val) ? acc: Number(val) , 0);
  my_books[max + 1] = obj;
  return my_books;
}


console.log(push({
    name: "Book_3",
    price: "300"
  }));

  console.log(push({
    name: "Book_4",
    price: "400"
  }));
```